# I can't start torch in device with API <=22(Used Android Studio and Unity) .why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins

Hi friends I'm trying to make torch application in unity.From documentation I have noticed that setTorchMode() is applicable only if we have API>22. It works fine for API>22.But for below API<23 I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703545/what-is-the-alternative-for-settorchmode-in-api-21-and-22). But even though my application in not staring torch in API<23 . From Logcat I have traced that `CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera`

Detail Error Report:

```
08-18 09:27:22.343 758-835/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 
14121:com.google.android.partnersetup/u0a7 (adj 15): DHA:empty #19
08-18 09:27:22.343 196-2615/? W/ServiceManager: Permission failure: 
android.permission.CAMERA from uid=10242 pid=14010
08-18 09:27:22.343 196-2615/? E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't 
use the camera pid=14010, uid=10242
08-18 09:27:22.343 14010-14051/? W/CameraBase: An error occurred while 
connecting to camera: 0
08-18 09:27:22.353 14010-14051/? E/ContentValues: TorchMode: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
`enter code here`at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:568)
 at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:426)
 at 
com.mugames.torchlibrary.AndroidTrochClass.TorchMode
(AndroidTrochClass.java:64)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my C# (Unity Code)

```
private void Awake()
{
    if(!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera))
    {
        Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
    }
}

void Start()
{
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject context = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
    javaObject = new AndroidJavaObject("com.mugames.torchlibrary.AndroidTrochClass");
    javaObject.Call("Init", context);
    javaObject.Call("TorchMode", true);
}
```

Also Here is my Java code(Name of JAVA class is AndroidTrochClass) for API<23

```
        try {
            if(camera== null && parameters==null) {
                camera = Camera.open();
                parameters = camera.getParameters();

                List<String> modesAvailable = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
                if (modesAvailable.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                } else if (modesAvailable.contains((Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON))) {
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Unity", "No Flash Available");
                }
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
            }
            if (state) {
                camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                camera.stopPreview();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "TorchMode: ",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

NOTE: I'm using Java Class Just as Plugin So Java Class extend to nothing so I have passed current context to Java Methods

Comment: Is it AndroidTrochClass  or AndroidTorchClass?

Comment: I have spelled wrong torch to troch but I think it is not problem Since I used same name to call that method from C#("com.mugames.torchlibrary.AndroidTrochClass")

Comment: Ok, no worries. Please edit your question for more clarity. There are some confusing parts. For ease, just follow this structure
1. Problem statement
2. What is working
3. What is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!! I need to add Camera permission in manifest file ;)